# Flowtype: Typehinting class based HOC component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm trying to typehint a HOC that adds a certain prop to a passed Component, like this:

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import type { ComponentType } from 'react';

type Props = {
  x: string,
}

const withReferral = <PassedProps: {}>(
    WrappedComponent: ComponentType<PassedProps>
): ComponentType<$Diff<PassedProps, Props>> => {
  class withReferral extends Component<PassedProps> {
    render() {
      return (<WrappedComponent {...this.props} x={'test'} />);
    }
  }

  return withReferral;
};

export default withReferral;
```

The error I get is this: 
"Cannot return withReferral because a callable signature is missing in statics of withReferral [1] but exists in
React.StatelessFunctionalComponent [2]."

With [1] referencing to `return withReferral` and [2] referencing to a React definition: `React$StatelessFunctionalComponent<Props>`

Anyone that has any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing that the type of `x` needs to be potentially missing from the WrappedComponents props. As noted in the [Flow HOC docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/hoc/#toc-injecting-props-with-a-higher-order-component), the type of the injected property needs to be a union with `void` e.g. `x: string | void`.

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import type { ComponentType } from 'react';

type Props = {
  x: string | void,    // <<== HERE
}

const withReferral = <PassedProps: {}>(
    WrappedComponent: ComponentType<PassedProps>
): ComponentType<$Diff<PassedProps, Props>> => {
  class withReferral extends Component<PassedProps> {
    render() {
      return (<WrappedComponent {...this.props} x={'test'} />);
    }
  }

  return withReferral;
};

export default withReferral;
```

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gEoCmAhgMY4A0oA3qAMKwawB2hzeAvqJFo6AORYS5fgG4UTXKBwBPdIRr1GmVuwAqchVx59BwnGMSJZ80AAVe6AM6gAvDUShQADwBcoKzizJmAc1AAPqAAbrDIACYUiBxGpCyeoPDIOAAWRJCEWFjE0HagADxmxFZWhOEWsNbu1BwAfAAUjk6gAOrZ6PLhDEyqOO7dKmw4GvKFxaXllla1iACU-cosQyOE+QAkACLIkJBjJWUV1lSH07V2Z9RNpNDjiclphBlZOaCEzjhs4TYDS+x7EycLk0nEJmOFMvVZg5ms0hDgAK5YZiger5NrEDplH69GgAOnxqWQVlx6CmXGctmo-A+nn4XGAtVm4hhMScMSacMRyKSqXSmWy0HEHHEiDemCk4MgxHh0DwPIeTwFoiAA))

Comment: Thanks, this indeed fixed the problem!